# How to Hide Cash On Delivery Payment Method from woo commerce checkout page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment-method

How to Hide Cash On Delivery Payment Method from woo commerce checkout page When Customer Select any Addon with any product?

Answer (score -1):

/* Hide free shipping please try below code */

```
function hide_free_shipping( $rates, $package ) { 
   
    if (  ) // as per your requirement add condition here
    { 
        foreach( $rates as $rate_id => $rate_val ) { 
            if ( 'free_shipping' === $rate_val->get_method_id() ) { 
                unset( $rates[ $rate_id ] );
            } 
        } 
    } 
    return $rates; 
} 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_free_shipping', 100, 2 );
```

Comment: How would this answer the question?